# Which non empty sets give $(A\cap B)\cup C = A\cap (B\cup C)$ but not $(A\cap B)\cup C = A\cap (B\cup C)$ and vice versa?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So in my discrete math course, there is a question in the chapter of sets:

[image: Ven Diagram]

I don't understand, how can different integers decide if (a) or (b) is true or false? Shouldn't it always be the case for any integers in the sets that (a) is always true and (b) can never be true or vice versa?

I have marked the area which is covered. Regardless if we're talking about (a) or (b), they cover the same area in the sets. Why would changing the numbers around change whether they are true or not? What is the solution to this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your contention about the shaded areas is not *quite* right.

The expression `(A ∩ B) ∪ C` is the *intersection* of `A` and `B`, then unioned with all of `C`. That does *not* include the stuff in `B` that's not in `A` or `C` as well. In other words, it does not include `4` or `5`.

Additionally, `A ∩ (B ∪ C)` could not contain anything that wasn't in `A` (since it's an intersection of something with `A`), so `4`, `5`, `8`, `9` and `10` would be out.

In fact, if you work out what the expressions are, you'll see:

```
(A ∩ B) ∪ C : 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
A ∩ (B ∪ C) : 3, 6, 7
```

So these are unequal sets with the data you've provided. One way to *make* them equal is just to remove the set difference (`8`, `9` and `10`) totally. All three sets are still non-empty as per the requirements:

```
A = { 1, 2, 3, 6, 7 }
B = { 3, 4, 5, 6 }
C = { 6, 7 }
```

but the two different expressions now evaluate the same:

```
(A ∩ B) ∪ C : 3, 6, 7
A ∩ (B ∪ C) : 3, 6, 7
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer, you are correct. Sorry for posting it on the wrong part of stackoverflow. Will post on math exchange in the future. But you explained it in a good way, gave u thumbs up and accepted your answer.